# Counting a particular value in a particular column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe "My_data" like this:

```
var1, var2, var3 
123,   234, 678
443,   567, fd
324,   678, 789
12,    102, fd
```

I would like to extract/count or calculate the percentage that "fd" occurs in the last column in "Var3", so in this example the output put should be:
    output:2 
or
    output: 0.50

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.shape` to count the number of rows satisfying the criteria, and you won't have to import anything else.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'var1': [123, 443, 324, 12],
     'var2': [234, 567, 678, 102],
     'var3': [678, "fd", 789, "fd"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df[df['var3']=="fd"].shape[0]/df.shape[0]
```

This should give you `0.5`. If you want just the count, use `df[df['var3']=="fd"].shape[0]`.

Comment: Thank you, it gave me exactly the same thing that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward way:

Pull absolute number of occurrences:

```
My_data['var3'].value_counts(normalize=False).loc['fd']
2
```

Pull percent of records:

```
My_data['var3'].value_counts(normalize=True).loc['fd']
0.5
```

And this method is faster/more efficient:

```
%timeit df.var3.value_counts(normalize=True).loc['fd']
1000 loops, best of 3: 597 µs per loop

%timeit df[df['var3']=="fd"].shape[0]/df.shape[0]
The slowest run took 16.34 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 710 µs per loop
```

Comment: Edited- used my default `df` variable. Renamed dataframe to `My_data`.

Comment: Yes, this one is also work but with a bit change:           My_data['var3'].value_counts(normalize=True).loc['fd']. Thank you.

Comment: `My_data.var3` and `My_data['var3']` is completely interchangeable.